# How to Programmatically Detect Interop-unlocked Windows Phone devices?

Tags: security, windows-phone, jailbreak, unlock

is there any mechanism, that can be implemented in Windows Phone app, in order to detect if the targeted device is interop-unlock or not ? I was thinking about a routine that is able to both identify eventually platform anomalies and pass the Windows Phone Store certification process.

Thanks.